# string is showing spaces where there are extra comma while splitting

Tags: asp.net

I have a following string in text format.

```
XSP,6919,LONWW38ST,,1,GBP,2055.94,382.94,,EK,BHX,,0,HYD,,0,C=IN,061114,4,45,10,2014,,251114,2,48,10,2014,,19,DNS,,,,,20131212112902,,,,,1345,EK,1,,061114,1325,071114,0015,BHX,,DXB,3,EK,EK,,40,77W,M,M,,LCA,Y,2,,071114,0345,071114,0840,DXB,3,HYD,,EK,EK,,526,345,M,M,,LCA,Y,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,3115,BA,3,,251114,0655,251114,1215,HYD,,LHR,5,BA,BA,,276,788,Y,M,,LCA,Y,4,,251114,1825,251114,1935, R,Y,1,2,,,,,MLSOWGB1,RP,,,ADT,3,4,,,,,YOW,RP,,,ADT,5,,,,,,XOW,RP,,,ADT,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

I read the string using following code

```
    string fileName = @"C:\Test.txt";

    string str = string.Empty;
    string s;
    if (File.Exists(fileName))
    {
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileName);
        String line;

        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if (line.Trim() != string.Empty)
            {
                string[] text = line.Split(',');
                Response.Write(text[0]);

            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
       s = "File does not exists";
    }
```

But the string is showing spaces where there are extra comma (,) when I am splitting the string. I want to ignore that space ans show the string in Grid View and also save in Database.

Please Help!

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use the second parameter of the `Split` method:

```
string[] text = line.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

However, I'd expect that doing that in this case is a bad idea. The "duplicate" comma probably means that the column is empty (assuming you're parsing a CSV file).

You may want to look for a good CSV parsing library instead - parsing a CSV isn't as easy as it looks on first glance :)

Comment: Thanks!! please tell how can I parse the string in csv format

Comment: @rahulaggarwal: That's not a good fit for StackOverflow, since you're basically asking us to write a (trivial) application for you. Basically, you'd create a DataTable, fill it with the wanted columns and rows and then you can assign this DataTable to the GridView's DataSource property. Inserting into database can also be done in a lot of different ways you can easily find on Google, for example :)